# Synaptics Touch Pad disables after login

Tags: kde-plasma, nixos

I'm on KDE using plasma5 on NixOS, and for some reason my touch pad is disabling after logging in with KDM. Here is the [output](http://lpaste.net/113377) of `synclient -l` right after booting. What would cause this issue? Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem with KDE on debian with my t440p and opened an issue for the synaptics package. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=770923

But I found a workaround in the ubuntu forum to use "imps". It has the disadvantage that you can't disable the touchpad an the virtual buttons separately. Better than nothing. Maybe it might help you too.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working/262364#262364?newreg=acf9a725adb249169b5dad26ac731c17

Try:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Answer (score 0):

**make some changes in your grub file:**

1.sudo nano /etc/default/grub 
2.Add “i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux” to  the line which says 3.GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”…”. 
4.sudo update-grub
5.sudo  apt-get install kde-config-touchpad && synaptiks

**edit touchpad file:**
6.sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/restart_touchpad.sh 
7. Enter the following code:

```
         #!/bin/sh

         case “$1” in
           resume)
               modprobe -r psmouse
               modprobe psmouse
         esac
         exit 0
```

7.sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/restart_touchpad.sh 
8.sudo reboot.
follow all step correctly.